# How to restrict access with Cloud NAT?

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, ibm-cloud, google-kubernetes-engine, nat

I have private GKE cluster on the GCP, and container registry outside the GCP(IBM Cloud Repository).
To pull image from ICR to GKE,I set Cloud Nat to GKE so that GKE can access to internet.
But in this case, GKE will be able to access to all internet IP address.

Is there any solution to restrict cloud Nat to access to only specified internet IP address?

I know that setting FW into GKE is the one way,is there any other solution?

Edit:
**Cloud routes**  seems to be a nice solution.

https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-routes?hl=ja#addingroute

Comment: Did you have a look to Cloud NAT rules? https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/nat-rules-overview

Comment: Yes, I tried. To my understanding, Cloud NAT rules is used to change NAT IP address according to target internet addresses.I couldn't set deny rules to restrict access.

Comment: There is no way in Cloud NAT to acheive what you are describing. The issue is that on the IBM side you are probably talking to the repository via an FQDN which can resolve to any random Internet IP. Unless you have control over what IP the IBM side resolves to (in which case you use Firewall Rule). I don't think there is a way to do what you want

Comment: Hmm, I agree, it's only a matching rule. Sorry, I'm really bad in networking. So, firewall rules are the solution I guess.